# Types of Peer-to-peer connection

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am developing an application and trying to use an peer-to-peer communication. i have idea about bluetooth and WIFI.

Is their any other options for peer-to-peer communication. Is it possible using Internet option.

Please help me with a source code or any documentation?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Apple's Documentation on the [GameKit](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html). That provides you exactly with what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

WIFI is internet.  I'm not quite sure what you mean.